# Resolving [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException] ManyToOne Column name `id` referenced for relation from Comment towards User does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Class Comment

```
/**
 * @var \Caerus\AppBundle\Entity\Users
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User" , inversedBy="comment")
 * 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 * 
 */
protected $user;
```

Class User

```
/**
* @var mixed
*
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="user")
*/
protected $comment;
```

Basically quite simple. I need the comments class to have a `user_id` field which is a direct copy of the original `user_id` field from the users class.
The error is as following:

> [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException] ManyToOne Column name `id` referenced for relation from Comment towards User does not exist

Why exactly is it still saying doesn't exist and how do I solve that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Referenced Column name should be the "id" property of the User class.

```
/**
 * @var \Caerus\AppBundle\Entity\Users
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User" , inversedBy="comment")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * 
 */
protected $user;
```

P.S.

- I would also name the OneToMany property "comments" as it holds many Comment objects.
- "@var \Caerus\AppBundle\Entity\Users" should be ...\User  as your class is called User

Comment: I suppose you have an "id" property in the User class, which is the primary key.. @ORM\Id()

Comment: That did the trick ! Thanks man. I originally had user_id as the property name but renamed later to id for standardization and that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Running `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` will give you more insight into which entity classes and columns are involved in the error condition.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this code:

```
/**
* @var \Caerus\AppBundle\Entity\Users
*
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User" , inversedBy="comment")
*
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true , referencedColumnName="variable_id_of_comment")
*/

protected $user;
```